# What is the closure of the set of homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, approximation-theory

I was wondering whether there are any theorems on the closure w.r.t. the $L^p$-norm, $p\in[1,\infty]$, of the set of continuous bijective functions with continuous inverse defined on a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Any type of information would be helpful, e.g. what certainly does not lie in the closure, necessary conditions for the limits of such functions,...

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^d$ is not compact so there are no such homeomorphisms. Do you mean embeddings?

Comment: I meant to define a homeomorphism on a compact set to ensure that the $L^p$-norm would be well-defined. Certainly one can't reach the entirety of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with that condition; that's why I added that one has to restrict the image to ensure surjectivity. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You are just misusing the word. A homeomorphism between two topological spaces $X, Y$ is, by definition, a continuous map with a continuous inverse, and there is no such map from $K$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$. The thing I believe you're talking about is called an embedding, which is a continuous map which is a homeomorphism onto its image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding

Comment: You're right, I made an edit.